# Unable to split USB devices to Different USB Busses. Is this a hardware issue or Linux issue

Tags: linux, qemu, linux-kvm, usb-c, virt-manager

I have i9-13900k CPU running on Asus Z790 MB.
When using lsusb. I found out that every USB device is assigned to BUS 1. It does not matter which USB port I use on the computer. I would like to Split the USB devices to Diffrent BUSes so that I can passthrough a PCI of a BUS to a VM. It is even more strange then that. I have 3 USBC (thinderbolts) on this PC. Each is on a separate PCI bus. When connecting a USBc HUB to any of the USBC ports all the devices in that hub are also on BUS 1. It seems to me that Linux does this assignment. How can I change the assignment of the USB devices to a different bus when They are connected to the USBC hub. If this is not possible, how can I pass an entire thunderbolt port to a VM. When I pass the PCI address of the TB to the VM. it is not "seen" by the VM.

lsusb:

```
Bus 004 Device 003: ID 0bda:0411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. Hub
Bus 004 Device 002: ID 05e3:0626 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 004: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 174c:3074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 SuperSpeed hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0451:8140 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 008: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 012: ID 046d:c083 Logitech, Inc. G403 Prodigy Gaming Mouse
Bus 001 Device 009: ID 413c:2005 Dell Computer Corp. RT7D50 Keyboard
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 174c:2074 ASMedia Technology Inc. ASM1074 High-Speed hub
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0b05:1a53 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. USB Audio
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 043e:9a39 LG Electronics USA, Inc. 27UP850 - WK.AEUDCSN - External Monitor 4K
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0451:ace1 Texas Instruments, Inc. TPS65982
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0451:8142 Texas Instruments, Inc. TUSB8041 4-Port Hub
Bus 001 Device 018: ID 8087:0033 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 029: ID 046d:c539 Logitech, Inc. Lightspeed Receiver
Bus 001 Device 028: ID 056e:0128 Elecom Co., Ltd TrackBall Mouse M-XPT1MR Wired
Bus 001 Device 030: ID 0911:0c1c Philips Speech Processing SpeechMike III
Bus 001 Device 027: ID 258a:0005 SINO WEALTH USB KEYBOARD
Bus 001 Device 026: ID 0bda:5411 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5411 Hub
Bus 001 Device 016: ID 05e3:0610 Genesys Logic, Inc. Hub
Bus 001 Device 013: ID 0b05:18f3 ASUSTek Computer, Inc. AURA LED Controller
Bus 001 Device 014: ID 1b1c:0c32 Corsair CORSAIR iCUE COMMANDER Core
Bus 001 Device 010: ID 058f:6254 Alcor Micro Corp. USB Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

lsusb -t:

```
    |__ Port 2: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 03.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/2p, 480M
/:  Bus 02.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/9p, 20000M/x2
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 4, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 5000M
/:  Bus 01.Port 1: Dev 1, Class=root_hub, Driver=xhci_hcd/16p, 480M
    |__ Port 4: Dev 2, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 4, If 0, Class=, Driver=, 1.5M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 1, Class=Communications, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 6, If 2, Class=CDC Data, Driver=cdc_acm, 12M
    |__ Port 5: Dev 3, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 3, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 4, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 5, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 6, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 480M
    |__ Port 6: Dev 5, If 7, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 480M
    |__ Port 7: Dev 7, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 1: Dev 9, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 2: Dev 11, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 8: Dev 8, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
    |__ Port 10: Dev 10, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 13, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
        |__ Port 3: Dev 13, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 12, If 0, Class=Vendor Specific Class, Driver=, 12M
    |__ Port 11: Dev 12, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 13: Dev 14, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
        |__ Port 4: Dev 16, If 0, Class=Hub, Driver=hub/4p, 480M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 17, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 1: Dev 17, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 1.5M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 20, If 0, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 20, If 1, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 20, If 2, Class=Audio, Driver=snd-usb-audio, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 20, If 3, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 20, If 4, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 20, If 5, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 2: Dev 20, If 6, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 18, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 18, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 3: Dev 18, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 19, If 0, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 19, If 1, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
            |__ Port 4: Dev 19, If 2, Class=Human Interface Device, Driver=usbhid, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 15, If 0, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
    |__ Port 14: Dev 15, If 1, Class=Wireless, Driver=btusb, 12M
```

Comment: I think you mean Thunderbolt not thinderbolts but it’s unclear if your talking about TB2 or a newer TB revision

Comment: perhaps the output of `lsusb -t` would paint a better picture of what you have connected where

Comment: There are 3 thunderbolts port 3 or Latest generation. They can also be used for display of the iGPU. I edited the post with "lsusb -t" when a hub of 4 USB devices was connected to one of the TB ports. As you can see they were assigned to BUS 1 like all the USB devices, which is the problem